# Three.js LOD object not rendering any models

Tags: three.js

so I'm experimenting with the `LOD` object in `Three.js` however I'm having trouble getting it to work. The code that i am using (excluding some standard setup code like creating a scene etc.) is shown here:

```js
let treeHighDetail = new THREE.Object3D();
let treeLowDetail = new THREE.Object3D();

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
gltfLoader.load('./resources/low_poly_tree.glb', (gltf) => {
    console.log(gltf)
    treeLowDetail.add(gltf.scene);
    treeLowDetail.traverse(c => {
        c.castShadow = true;
    })

})


gltfLoader.load('./resources/tree.glb', (gltf) => {
    console.log(gltf)
    treeHighDetail.add(gltf.scene);
    treeHighDetail.traverse(c => {
        c.castShadow = true;
    })
})

const lod = new THREE.LOD();
let treeMesh = treeHighDetail.clone();
lod.addLevel(treeMesh, 5);

treeMesh = treeLowDetail.clone();
lod.addLevel(treeMesh, 20);

scene.add(lod);
```

I have two tree models, one low poly and one relatively high. I am attempting to have the high poly tree be displayed when i am close to the object, and the low poly tree render when i am further away from it. Running this code doesn't produce any errors in the console, however none of the models are rendered into the scene at any distance. Any ideas on what the issue could be would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the glTF asset *before* they have been loaded. The above `load()` method calls are asynchronously so you have to wait for their completion.

There are different ways to achieve this. You could create an instance of `THREE.LoadingManager`, use it as an argument for `GLTFLoader`'s constructor call and then use its `onLoad()` callback for creating the LODs.

Or you rewrite your code to use the async/await pattern which is probably the more elegant solution. It would look like so:

```js
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

const [ gltfLowDetail, gltfHighDetail ] = await Promise.all( [
    gltfLoader.loadAsync( './resources/low_poly_tree.glb' ),
    gltfLoader.loadAsync( './resources/tree.glb' ),
] );

const treeLowDetail = new THREE.Object3D();
const treeHighDetail = new THREE.Object3D();

treeLowDetail.add(gltfLowDetail.scene);
treeLowDetail.traverse(c => {
    c.castShadow = true;
})

treeHighDetail.add(gltfHighDetail.scene);
treeHighDetail.traverse(c => {
    c.castShadow = true;
})

const lod = new THREE.LOD();
let treeMesh = treeHighDetail.clone();
lod.addLevel(treeMesh, 5);

treeMesh = treeLowDetail.clone();
lod.addLevel(treeMesh, 20);

scene.add(lod);
```

You have to ensure the function/method holding this code is `async` as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, i couldn't find anything even remotely related to this solution to the  issue however this is working now, thanks again :))

Comment: Great! Please upvote and accept the answer in this case.